# When I draw with CustomPaint after a while it lags #103968

Tags: flutter, dart, paint

I know there are other issues related to this problem, I found them, I read them and I still could not solve my problem.

If you could help me by viewing the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103968) from GitHub, since there I could see it in more detail, thank you very much.

Comment: Yes ! it is in the section code sample at the end

Comment: I thing issue is too many `point` in `pointList`. after a while of drawing, the list scale up but the `CustomPaint` rerender all the point cause the lags. Maybe someway to check and only render newest point will solve problem

Comment: Hey bro, does you solve the problem yet?

Comment: Yes, but what caused me lag was the BlocObserver, which printed in console every point and change, so making it infinite and making me slow that :S, so I commented and no longer lag haha

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but can you try and let me know the results, here's an idea of mine. I have never used **bloc** nor am I in a position to test this idea. Hope it help.

**Problem**: I think too many **points** being rendered is the cause of lags.

**Idea**: split the list **points** into many small arrays and render them with separate CustomPaints (using Stack on top of each other). `CustomPain.shouldRepaint` also needs to rewrite the conditions so that they only rerender when there is a change in **pointsList**. Now the app will only rerender newest part of **pointList**, not all as before.

```dart
//...
// In previus, everytime this changes, app rerender all item.
pointList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...];

// Now with shouldRepaint, old part will not rerender, only with newest part
pointListParts = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [...],
]


return RepaintBoundary(
  child: Stack( // Stack CustomPaint, cause shouldRepaint, old CustomPaint part will not rerendered
    children: pointListParts.map((part){
      return CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: DrawingPainter(part),
      );
    }).toList(),
  ),
);
//...

class DrawingPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<DrawnShape>? shapeList;
  // ...
  
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawingPainter oldDelegate) => shapeList != oldDelegate.shapeList; // edit condition to repaint
}
```

Comment: I will save your code and write a similar one when I have free time, hope you don't mind

Comment: Yep don't worry, just in the pointListParts.map is the List, right ? cause in the "part" comes the DrawnShape, so in the DrawingPainter is getting the class not the list

Comment: @DanielRoldán Yup, totaly my idea is "each painter draw some point, the painter that take enough point don't rerender"